# Исключение InputMismatchException при вводе в функции nextInt()

Tags: java

Не понимаю, почему не работает ввод строки `purchName`? Если поменять местами 20 и 21 строку местами, то считывает число, и когда доходит до ввода строки, выдаёт ошибку. В чём проблема?

```
    ArrayList<Integer> balance = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<String> purchase = new ArrayList<>();

    System.out.println("Введите ваш бюджет на месяц: ");
    int budget = in.nextInt();

    System.out.println("У вас есть " + budget + " до конца месяца.");

    for (int i = 0; i <= budget; i--) { // circle that responds for re-entering purchase
        System.out.println("Name of Purchase And its Price: ");

        String purchName = (String) System.in.read();
        int purchPrice = in.nextInt(); // ошибка возникает тут

        System.out.println("Thanks!");

        balance.add(purchPrice);
        purchase.add(purchName);

        int value = budget - purchPrice;

        System.out.println("If you want continue write 1");
        System.out.println("See you purchase 2");
    }
}
```

Вывод:

```
Введите ваш бюджет на месяц: 
20
У вас есть 20 до конца месяца.
Name of Purchase And its Price: 
qwer
Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
    at java.base/java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:939)
    at java.base/java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1594)
    at java.base/java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2258)
    at java.base/java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2212)
    at com.begin.exampleTwo.main(exampleTwo.java:23)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: Вы забыли начало кода добавить. Акуратней маркируйте копируемый текст, если неудобно мышкой, воспользуйтесь клавиаурой.

Answer (score 1):

Тот код, что ты привёл, в принципе не компилируется из-за `String purchName = (String) System.in.read();`, потому что `read` возвращает `int`.

Соответственно, исполняется у тебя какая-то последняя валидная старая версия, которая выдаёт ошибку на `nextInt` (который у тебя судя по всему раньше стоял сразу после `Name of Purchase And its Price:`

Замени `(String) System.in.read()` на `in.nextLine()`.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Scratch {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("text");
        String text = s.nextLine();
        System.out.println("integer");
        int i = s.nextInt();
        System.out.println(text+", "+i);
    }
}
```

Выдаёт

```
text
some text
integer
12
some text, 12
```